# Checking if two variables are independent or not

Tags: probability

Suppose that we choose $X, Y ∈ \{0,1\}$ independently and we set
W = (X . Y)

> 1 - Are the random variables $X$ and $W$ independent?
>
> 2 - Are $X$ and $W$ independent if we are given the value of $Y$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Check whether

1. $$\Pr\{Z=z,X=x\}=\Pr\{Z=z\}\Pr\{X=x\}$$
2. $$\Pr\{Z=z,X=x|Y=y\}=\Pr\{Z=z|Y=y\}\Pr\{X=x|Y=y\}$$